# Is there a way to check if my site visitor has visited another site?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, javascript

I want to know if the current visitor has already visited a specific site. The site is owned by someone else and is on a different domain.

Is there a way?

Comment: Not generally, this would be a breach of privacy.

Comment: @MechMK1 aren't 3rd party cookies a way to do this?

Comment: @schroeder You'd need to have a presence on that site to get the cookie set up wouldn't you?

Comment: @user I'm not sure about the implementation details, but I thought that you didn't. The 3rd party needed to do that.

Comment: At one time it was possible to include links to other specific sites and have javascript return the **color** of the link, assuming that a previously clicked link has a different color. I don't know if this is still a viable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally there is a way for Chrome. You can try to exploit [this vulnerability](https://favicon-leak.site/) (not a product, but a demo to check if it works in your browser).

The vulnerability uses JavaScript to check from which cache the image was delivered: from F-cache or from disk cache.

Note: This method will only work if target site has a favicon.

Comment: We try not to post products/services as answers. Include how the product/service meets the needs of the question.

Comment: @schroeder you have access to any favicon via img, and link tag. There are no CORS problems with that.

Comment: @MaximDvorkin really interesting method, thank you